# ¿Cómo importar a MySQL un fichero de texto con este formato?

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando importar los datos a la bd con una tabla ya definida con el mismo número de campos. Por medio de script SQL pero no estoy logrando importar los datos, creo que tiene que ver algo con el separador que hay en el fichero: '¶'

Script:

```
load data local infile 'c:\\ventas2.txt'
into table ventas 
fields terminated by '¶' 
lines terminated by '\r\n'
```

Formato de fichero,

```
006¶ACACENTRO¶23/11/2017¶286163¶23/11/2017¶06:54:20¶ACAE068329¶6385212¶9836760¶Þ
006¶ACACENTRO¶23/11/2017¶286163¶23/11/2017¶06:54:20¶ACAE068329¶6385271¶9836834¶Þ
006¶ACACENTRO¶23/11/2017¶286163¶23/11/2017¶06:54:20¶ACAE068329¶6385278¶9836843¶Þ
```

Answer (score 2):

Desde **phpMyAdmin**:

1) En una base de datos cualquiera, creas una tabla con el mismo nombre que el archivo.txt.

2) Creas una columna por cada tipo de dato que vas a insertar, yo usé la que te decribo abajo, a medida que veía qué tipo de dato tenían los datos de tus columnas le asigne un tipo de dato a la columna. (igualmente no sé porque la ultima columna falló).

Donde dice agenciabus ponele el nombre de la DB donde quieras crear la tabla, ése nombre me quedó re aleatorio.

> CREATE TABLE `agenciabus`.`prueba` ( `id` INT NOT NULL , `name`
>   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `fromDate` DATE NOT NULL , `numer` INT NOT NULL
>   , `toDate` DATE NOT NULL , `time` TIME NOT NULL , `field` VARCHAR(20)
>   NOT NULL , `number1` INT NOT NULL , `number2` INT NOT NULL , `letter`
>   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

3) Una vez creada la tabla vacía, vas a **importar**, seleccionas el archivo y abajo te da la opcion de importarlo de **sql** o **csv**, le das a **csv**, y dejás los **valores por defecto**.

Igualmente, esto es siguiendo unos pasos, no te lo hice por linea de código, tendría que bucear un poco más, sin embargo creo para responder la pregunta viene bien.

Probablemente desde otro administrador de mysql también funcione pero no hice la prueba.

Si te querés evitar errores fijate de borrar la última letra de cada dato que insertaste, parece una letra pero no es, y cada vez que quize hacer un insercción con eso me tiraba errores.

Por lo cual no tendrías que tener más advertencias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edito:**

Después de **probar** un poco, utilizando esta **consulta**:

> LOAD DATA INFILE "/prueba.txt" INTO TABLE prueba COLUMNS TERMINATED BY
>   ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

y colocando el archivo directamente en el **C:**, los datos se importaron por consulta, sin embargo borré las ultimas letras o símbolos que parecen un "p".

**Sino probá lo siguiente:**

> LOAD DATA INFILE "/prueba.txt" INTO TABLE prueba COLUMNS TERMINATED BY
>   '¶' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY
>   '\n';

**Previamente tenés que tener creada la tabla con un formato similiar al que te puse en un principio así toma todos los datos sin problemas**

Si tu problema es que tenés un archivo txt con muchos ¶, podés intentar hacer lo siguiente.

```
public class Panel {

    public Panel() {

        /* Tenemos un String original, donde vos copias los datos que tengas con ¶ */ 
        String original = "Hola¶mundo¶Hola¶mundo¶Hola¶mundo¶Hola¶mundo";

        /* Creamos un String aparte y le decimos que tome tome los "¶" y los reemplace por "," */
        String strRepaired = original.replace("¶", ",");

        /* Vemos por consola si se cambiaron los datos */
        System.out.println(strRepaired);

        /* Copia en un archivo nuevo lo que hay en la consola y fijate si podés importarlo de ésa manera */ 

    }

    /* Método inicializador de App */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panel p = new Panel();
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero perdón me equivoque en la publicación del fichero, el formato del fichero es con separaciones entre campos: ¶ . ¿Aún asi funcionaría?

Comment: Bueno, respondí según lo que leí principalmente en la pregunta, hacé las pruebas correspondientes, tanto la primer forma como la consulta que te dejé funcionan muy bien.

Comment: gracias, pero creo que no funciona colocando en el script columnas terminadas por: ¶

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es porqué tenés que usar ése simbolo, si lo que querés no es importar los datos?

Comment: porque el archivo tiene cientos o hasta miles de registros, con más columnas agregadas pero todo el fichero viene ya separado por ese simbolo. No es que yo lo quiera usar, es el fichero que me dierón el que ya lo trae.

Comment: bueno mirá la respuesta, te voy a mostrar como podés hacer para que en ése txt le cambies los "¶" por "," , cambiar ése simbolo por comas.

Comment: probaré, gracias